# Php database issue (Zend framework and Google Calendar)

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I'm new to php and zend framework, I've got this display screen which customer is updating their classes information through Google calendar. Every time when I delete a data eg a 9am yoga class through phpmyadmin data base, the data disappears on the display screen, but I can still see the 9am yoga class on the google calendar.

How are they all connected? Is Zendframe going to update the 9am yoga class back again (which shows not so far)?

Also I've found gdata_process.php, everytime I run this php url through, the data comes back, and it wouldn't let me delete the coming back data again from phpmyadmin, how come?

Any help to clear my head would be appreciated. I can post some code if I'm confusing anyone.

Thanks
S:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have Google Calendar which saves the data in google's database. And not on yours .

So what exactly you want to do is either go and remove it from google calendar ( manually ) as the data is being imported by the script to the database. What ever value you change in your database via phpmyadmin is not going to effect the google's calendar .

Or you can write a script to delete the google calendar value. I have not tried it , so not sure how much scope is there for it .

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My problem was that google calendar wasn't updating the phpmyadmin/the developing site, I have found the solution by adding gdata_calendar.php into cron jobs setting in cPanel. Can one google calendar update two databases/two sites together? Thanks for your help, S:)

Comment: Yes, get 2 connections and run the update on both. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help Hari! Cheers, S:)